# Changing the tintColor of an imageView does not work when selected

Tags: ios, swift

I made a custom menu bar and now I want to implement a slider for the navigation. I set the first Image as selectedItem with the color .white and the other images with .gray .. Now i want to click on the other images and change the .tintColor of it.

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {

return imageView
    }()

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? .white : .gray
        }
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            imageView.tintColor = isHighlighted ? .white : .white
        }
    }



}
```

I should be able to click on the other images and change the tintColor while it deselects the other image.

Comment: Try commenting `cell.tintColor = .white` from `cellForItemAt` method.

Comment: Didn´t work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some inconsistency in `collectionView's` `cellForItemAt` method `collectionViewCell's` `isSelected`.

1. In `cellForItemAt`, you are setting `cell.tintColor = .white`
2. In `isSelected`, you are setting `imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? .white : .gray`

Try changing the code in `cellForItemAt` to,

```
cell.imageView.tintColor = .gray
```

I've created a sample code so you can identify the issue,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.imageView.tintColor = .gray
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? .white : .gray
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It didnt work me..  Do I need to change code in the didSelectItemAt method maybe?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/K7QaiifY) you go. I tried your solution in another project and its working just fine.. I don´t know why its not working in my current project. I think there might be some failes with some constraints or I didnt initialise the imageView correctly in MenuCell

Comment: Add the code for `BaseCell`. And where are you adding `MenuBar` view?

Comment: [BaseCell](https://pastebin.com/vYvAaKTN) and [This](https://pastebin.com/mnq4qxh8) is the code for the menu bar. I initialise it in the viewDidLoad of my HomeViewController with setUpMenuBar()

Comment: changing the vertical constraints did it for me.. at least I can grab the elements now and change the color.. But now all the images are in a scrollview in my collectionview... any way to disable the scrollview in it and center the elemets?

Comment: Can you add the screenshot so I can understand better?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/bAc5XOo) you go.. UICollectionView inheritates from scrollView.. but everytime I try to fix it with NSLayoutConstraints V:|[v0(50]| or what ever it kinda do what I expect but u cant access the images anymore

Comment: Check the constraints of `imageView` inside the `collectionView`.

Comment: Thanks.. you helped me a lot.. I went thorugh my code more than 10 times and didn´t see a thing.